# Lucene .net Boost not working when using * wildcard

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, lucene.net

I have two documents and using Luke to investigate, I have confirmed in code that it has the same behavior, using `StandardAnalyzer`.

Document one with boost 1

```
stored/uncompressed,indexed,tokenized<Description:Nummer ett>
stored/uncompressed,indexed,tokenized<Id:2>
stored/uncompressed,indexed,tokenized<Name:Apa>
```

Document two with boost 2

```
stored/uncompressed,indexed,tokenized<Description:Nummer två>
stored/uncompressed,indexed,tokenized<Id:1>
stored/uncompressed,indexed,tokenized<Name:Apa>
```

Search apa in field Name
Returns with boost used and in the correct order.

```
Document 2 has Score 1,1891
Document 1 has Score 0.5945
```

Search ap*
Returns in no order and same score

```
Document 1 Score 1.0000
Document 2 Score 1.0000
```

Search apa*
Returns in no order and same score

```
Document 1 Score 1.0000
Document 2 Score 1.0000
```

Why is this? I would like to return some documents with higher boost value even if I have to use wildcards. Is this possible?

Cheers all cool coders out there!

This is what I want to accomplice.

A search string and want matches. Using wildcard.
Search "Lu" +"*"

```
Document
 Name
 City
```

I would like the Document whose Name is Lund to get higher rating than the document with the Name Lunt or City is Lund for example. This is due to I will know which documents that are most popular. I want to get the documents with city Stockholm and names Stockholm and Stockholmen but ordered as I choose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since `WildcardQuery` is a subclass of `MultiTermQuery` you are getting constant score of 1.

If you check the definition of `t.getBoost()`:

> t.getBoost() is a search time boost of term t in the query q as
>   specified in the query text (see query syntax), or as set by
>   application calls to setBoost(). Notice that there is really no direct
>   API for accessing a boost of one term in a multi term query, but
>   rather multi terms are represented in a query as multi TermQuery
>   objects, and so the boost of a term in the query is accessible by
>   calling the sub-query getBoost()

http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html#formula_termBoost

One possible hack could be to set rewrite method of query parser:

```
myCustomQueryParser.SetMultiTermRewriteMethod(MultiTermQuery.SCORING_BOOLEAN_QUERY_REWRITE)
```

Comment: This is an answer I had very hard time to find both looking in the book and searching. Thank you, it will be much easier to solve the problem knowing how it works.

Comment: It did help but perhaps not all the way yet, will work on it. I though it would be simple because my problem is something I think many would want.

Comment: Why is the SetMultiTermReWriteMethod considered a hack?