# Search Results Sort order using Sitecore 7 ContentSearch API?

Tags: lucene, sitecore, sitecore7

I am using the `Sitecore.ContentSearch` API to perform a search which works fine and brings back the expected results.

```
searchResults = context.GetQueryable<SearchItem>()
    .Where(i => i.Name.Contains(searchTerm));
```

I have then added a `Boosting Rule` at `/sitecore/system/Settings/Indexing and Search/Boosting Rules/Item Rules` which checks a boolean value on the item and if its true boosts the score, the rule has been applied via Standard Values on the Item template.

The issue I have is the order of the results returned from the GetQueryable call do not match the results I am expecting.

If I run the same query in `Luke v3.5` I get the expected results back ordered by the Score desc.

Does anyone know why the call to GetQueryable results would be in a different order?

`Update - Additional Rule Details`

**Rule**

[image]

**Item Template**

[image]

Comment: Hi Wesley,can you give us more information about boosting rule? Do you put boost value on template fields ?

Comment: I am using the Rules Engine to to define the rule and applying it via the Boosting Rules field.

Comment: What is the query you see? What do you expect and what do you eventually get back as result. Why does this not meet your expectations?

Comment: The order of the results from the Linq query do not seem to take in to account the boost applied to the template. However when I execute the same query through Luke the results are as I'd expect to see them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sitecore support have come back with the use of `boosting` is not supported when using `Contains` in Linq as this constructs a `Wildcard Query` in Lucene which does not support boosting.

Its discussed in a bit more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352404/lucene-net-boost-not-working-when-using-wildcard)