# lucene.net, document boost not working

Tags: sorting, indexing, lucene.net

i am a beginner & developing my very first project with lucene.net i.e. an address search utility, lucene.net 3.0.3

using standard analyzer, query parser, (suppose i have a single field, Stored & Analyzed as well)
 - sample data : (every row is a document with a single field)
(Postcode and street column concatenated)

- UB6 9AH Greenford Road something
- UB6 9AP Greenford Road something
- UB1 3EB Greenford Road something
- PR8 3JT Greenford Road something
- HA1 3QD something Greenford Road
- SM1 1JY something Greenford Road something

**Searching**

```
StringBuilder customQuery = new StringBuilder();
customQuery.Append(_searchFieldName + ":\"" + searchTerm + "\"^" + (wordsCount));
```

// this is for phrase matching

```
foreach (var word in words.Where(word => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(word)))
    {
        customQuery.Append(" +" + _searchFieldName + ":" + word + "*");
    }
```

// this is prefix match for each word

Query query = _parser.Parse(customQuery.ToString());

_searcher.Search(query, collector);

**all above (searching) working fine**

**Question**

if i search for "Greenford road" ,
**i may want that  row that has 'SM1' should come up (means i want to priorities result as per postcode)**

i have tested Query-Time-Boost and it works fine

but i may have a long list of priority postcodes sometimes (so i don't want to loop over each postcode and set its priority at query time

I WANT DOCUMENT TIME BOOSTING

but whatever document boost i set (at the time of indexing), it doesn't effect my search results

```
doc.Add(new Field(SearchFieldName, SearchField, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
if (condition == true)
{
   doc.Boost = 2; // or 5 or 200 etc (nothing works)
}
```

please HELP

i tried to understand similarity and scoring, but its too much mathematics there...

please help....

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem myself and I think it might be due to wildcard queries (It was in my case at least). There is another post here that explains the issue better, and provides a possible solution:

[Lucene .net Boost not working when using * wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352404/lucene-net-boost-not-working-when-using-wildcard)